# Check if windows service is automatic

Tags: batch-file, windows-services

I am trying to create a batch script to see if Windows service, ex. `wuauserv` is set to an automatic start. So far, I have tried

```
sc query [ServiceName] | findstr /i "STATE"
```

but this only shows me the running state, and I want to know if it is set to start automatically. Bonus points for an IF statement that checks the state.

**SOLUTION**
Here is the solution that I engineered thanks to the below people and others on SO. *Feel free to make improvements on [this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/TechnoTrumpet/a7951baeb4e9a477fb792897a78a2b80)*

```
@ECHO OFF 
ECHO This script re-enables Windows Update and sets it to Automatic. 
ECHO However, this script needs to be run as admin.
net.exe session 1>NUL 2>NUL || goto :not_admin
echo Sucess! You ran this script with Admin rights!
sc qc "wuauserv" | findstr /i AUTO_START > nul
goto :check

:check
if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 ( 
    ECHO The service is set to start automatically. 
    TIMEOUT 5
) ELSE ( 
    echo The service is NOT set to start automatically. Trying again. 
    sc config "wuauserv" start= auto
    net start wuauserv
    goto :check
) 
exit


:not_admin
echo ERROR: please run as admin 
TIMEOUT 10 /nobreak
exit
```

Comment: Better start with `sc qc wuauserv` to Query Configuration

Comment: sc qc wuauserv | findstr /i "START_TYPE" will show me what I want. How do I put this into an if statement?

Comment: Don't use a `if`, search for `AUTO_START` and check `errorlevel` value of `findstr` with `&&` conditional execution operator

Comment: Can you give me an example of that?

Comment: @TechnoTrumpet, why not just ignore my answer, and the bonus points you promised? Please note that the majority of the code you've added as an edit is not an answer to the question you posed. Just because a service isn't set to automatic start, doesn't mean it isn't running, you should consider it's state before asking it to start, and why not use `SC Start` instead of `Net Start`?

Comment: I just figured that `sc start` and `net start` were basically interchangeable. Is this not the case?

Comment: @TechnoTrumpet, if you're already using a particular executable, which is both newer and does the same job, why would you invoke an alternative one? And I would still appreciate some feedback on my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try this batch file, which takes the service name as a parameter and returns 0 if automatic, 1 if not:

```
@echo off

if [%1]==[] (
  echo Missing service name. Returning 2.
  exit /b 2
)

sc qc "%1" | findstr /i AUTO_START > nul

if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 (
  echo The "%1" service is set to start automatically. Returning 0.
  exit /b 0
) else (
  echo The "%1" service is NOT set to start automatically ^(or the service is inaccessible^). Returning 1.
  exit /b 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative option using win32_service via WMIC:

```bat
WMIC Service Where "Name='wuauserv' And StartMode='Auto'" Get State /Value 2>Nul|Find "State="||Echo Service is not set to Auto
```

---

If you wanted to change the start mode, should it not be set to automatic, you could probably do that as a single command too:

```bat
WMIC Service Where "Name='wuauserv' And StartMode!='Auto'" Call ChangeStartMode "Auto"
```